# Click to copy coordinates From QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, coordinates, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have a created some point data using CRS ESPG:4326 and added Google base map from OpenLayers plugin. While adding the Google Maps imagery I have changed CRS to ESPG:3857 in project properties.

[image]

Then I opened default Coordinate capture plugin

[image]

Now I want to copy the coordinates to the clipboard wherever I click in the map window. I am facing a problem while copying coordinates, when I click on copy to clipboard it is capturing coordinate system also. How to avoid this problem and can I automate this option?

Is there any plugin that allow us to press any shortcut key then captures the coordinates where ever the mouse is? If not how can we edit this plugin and recreate a plugin that can help us to do the same using Python?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, using newer versions of QGIS, there is a simple feature that does what you want without installing any plugin: simply right-click on the map canvas and you have the option to save this location's coordinates either in project CRS or in WGS84 (lon/lat in degrees).

[image]